# C++ overloading: switching from friend to member function

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, member-functions, friend-function

I have this code which I wish to switch from friend functions to member functions:

```
inline bool operator< (const MyClass& left, const MyClass& right)
{
    return (((left.value == 1) ? 14 : left.value) < ((right.value == 1) ? 14 : right.value));
}

inline bool operator> (const MyClass& left, const MyClass& right)
{
    // recycle <
    return  operator< (right, left);
}
```

I have got this far:

```
inline bool MyClass::operator< (const MyClass& right)
{

    return (((this->value == 1) ? 14 : this->value) < ((right.value == 1) ? 14 : right.value));
}

inline bool MyClass::operator> (const MyClass& right)
{
    // recycle <
    return  right.operator<(*this);
}
```

However, VC++ gives me this complain:

`cannot convert 'this' pointer from 'const MyClass' to 'MyClass &'`

How can I fix this?  Beside, is my `operator>` correctly written?

Comment: What is that `14`?

Comment: @Tas, MyClass is a class for card comparison.  So Ace is 1 and 14 at the same time.  That's how I do it.  But if you have better ideas, do let me know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both of your operators should be `const` class methods:

```
inline bool MyClass::operator< (const MyClass& right) const
{

    return (((this->value == 1) ? 14 : this->value) < ((right.value == 1) ? 14 : right.value));
}

inline bool MyClass::operator> (const MyClass& right) const
{
    // recycle <
    return  right.operator<(*this);
}
```

Note that in the `>` overload, `right` is a `const MyClass &`.

Therefore, `right.operator<` requires the `<` operator to be a `const` class method, because `right` is const. When you're playing games with a `const` object, you can only invoke its `const` methods. You cannot invoke its non-`const` methods.